# $2=(a+b\sqrt{10})(c+d\sqrt{10})\implies 2=(a-b\sqrt{10})(c-d\sqrt{10})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

> Why, $2=(a+b\sqrt{10})(c+d\sqrt{10})\implies 2=(a-b\sqrt{10})(c-d\sqrt{10})$

To show is, that $2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{10}]$ but not prime, everything is clear except the line above. So if the implication above is true, then I get an equation in $\mathbb Z$, $4=(a^2-10b^2)(c^2-10d^2)$ which has no nontrivial factorization, hence irreducibility is shown, BUT why $b$ and $d$ can change their signs ?

[image]

Comment: With the assumption that $(a,b,c,d)$ are rational, I guess?

Comment: @Did $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z$

Comment: Just divide $4 = (a^2-10b^2)(c^2-10d^2)$ by $2 = (a+b\sqrt{10})(c+d\sqrt{10})$.

Comment: Then add this to the question.

Comment: @SandeepSilwal: No, that won't work. He need to know $2=(a-b\sqrt{10})(c-d\sqrt{10})$ in order to _derive_ the equation for $4$ in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can work this out longhand.

Multiply the first expression out so that $$2=ac+10bd+(ad+bc)\sqrt {10}$$

Now this sets a rational number $2-ac-10bd$ equal to a multiple of $\sqrt {10}$. Since $\sqrt {10}$ is irrational, this multiple must be zero, so that $ad+bc=0$. And if this is true, you will find that the second expression comes to the same thing.

It is worth doing longhand to understand what Henning Makholm says in his solution (which is part of a more general theory)

Answer (score 4):

All quadratic number fields/rings come with a conjugation: $a+b\sqrt D \mapsto a-b\sqrt D$. This is clearly a homomorphism, so just apply that to the first equation.

Comment: what if $D$ is a square number ?

Comment: @inequal: Then $\mathbb Z[\sqrt D]$ is just $\mathbb Z$, and that's not usually considered a quadratic extension. (Presumably we know what the primes in $\mathbb Z$ are already, anyway). In any case, 10 is not square.

Comment: You can still consider $R=\mathbb Z[X]/\langle X^2-D\rangle$ for square $D$ -- conjugation still works fine there, but the ring would fail to be an integral domain.

Answer (score 2):

The point is that $\{1, \sqrt{10} \}$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, for otherwise, we have $x + y \sqrt{10} =0$ for some $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$ not both $0$, which implies that $\sqrt{10} \in \mathbb{Q}$, which is not the case ( by uniqueness of prime factorization in $\mathbb{Z}$, for example).

Now we have if we have $2 = (a+b \sqrt{10})(c+d\sqrt{10}) $ for $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$
then the linear independence of $\{1,\sqrt{10} \}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ forces $2 = ac +10bd$ and $ 0 = (ad+bc)$. But substituting this back also gives $2 = (a-b \sqrt{10})(c-d\sqrt{10})$.

This type of argument works with $\sqrt{10}$ replaced by $\sqrt{d}$ as long as $d$ is an integer which is not a perfect square.